# Use smart pointers and lambda functions - deletion of object

Tags: c++, lambda, smart-pointers, delete-operator

I want to implement a [JavaScript style timeout function](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_settimeout_cb_ms), that takes a callback and time delay and will execute the callback after the specified time amount is over. The `TimeOut` object should afterwards be destroyed.

The Code is executed in a context, that provides a cyclic code execution by calling an `onCycle()` method of a module. I want to utilize this cycle for checking if the time has passed, as no code execution outside of this cycle is senseful (this is due to hardware access, which is slow). In this example (see end of question), the cycle is faked by the `ManagerClass` and the cycle is called in an infinite loop.

As of now, I use a normal pointer that I pass through the capturing list of the lambda expression to call. I don't really like the way, I'm then deleting the pointer in the lambda execution:

```c++
void TimeOut::timeOut(const float &timeout, const std::function<void ()> &callback){
  TimeOut* t = new TimeOut();

  t->init(timeout, [t, callback]
  {
    callback();
    t->connection_.disconnect();
    delete t;
  });
}
```

My main problem here is, that I would prefer to use smart pointers. But if I do the following:

```c++
void TimeOut::timeOut(const float &timeout, const std::function<void ()> &callback){
  std::shared_ptr<TimeOut> t = std::make_shared<TimeOut>();

  t->init(timeout, [t, callback]
  {
    callback();
    t->connection_.disconnect();
    std::cout << t.use_count() << std::endl;
  });
}
```

The destructor of `TimeOut` will not be called and the reference counter of the `shared_ptr` counts one remaining reference.

**Is there a way to use smart pointers for this particular problem? Or am I forced to keep it the way it is now?**

See the (not so) minimal working example below.

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <cmath>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

class ManagerClass{
public:
  static boost::signals2::signal<void()> cycleSignal;
};

boost::signals2::signal<void()> ManagerClass::cycleSignal;

class TimeOut
{
private:
  /**
   * @brief TimeOut Creates a new timeout that will trigger a callback after a specified amount of time.

   * @param timeout the time in seconds from now, when the callback shall be executed.
   * @param callback the callback to execute after 'timeout' seconds.
   */
  void init(const float& timeout, const std::function<void ()>& callback);

  std::function<void ()> callback_;
  std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> pointOfExecution_;

  boost::signals2::connection connection_;
public:
  TimeOut();
  ~TimeOut();

  static void timeOut(const float& timeout, const std::function<void ()>& callback);

  void onCycle();
};

//IMPLEMENTATION of TimeOut:
TimeOut::TimeOut()
{
  connection_ = ManagerClass::cycleSignal.connect(std::bind(&TimeOut::onCycle, this));
}

TimeOut::~TimeOut()
{
  std::cout << "Destructor of TimeOut called!" << std::endl;
}


// getTimeDiff is a utility and is normally located elsewhere. Just for Completeness of the example.
inline float getTimeDiff(const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>& lastTime){
  std::chrono::duration<float> diff = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - lastTime;
  return diff.count();
}

void TimeOut::onCycle()
{
  if(getTimeDiff(pointOfExecution_) >= 0.0f ){
    callback_();
  }
}

void TimeOut::init(const float &timeout, const std::function<void ()> &callback)
{
  callback_ = callback;
  using namespace std::chrono;
  pointOfExecution_ = time_point<system_clock>(system_clock::now() + milliseconds(static_cast<int>(round(timeout * 1000.0f))));
}


void TimeOut::timeOut(const float &timeout, const std::function<void ()> &callback){
  TimeOut* t = new TimeOut();

  t->init(timeout, [t, callback]
  {
    callback();
    t->connection_.disconnect();
    delete t;
  });
}

// MAIN
int main()
{
  //This is the exact syntax on how I want the interface to look like.
  TimeOut::timeOut(2.0, []{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  });

  //This infinite loop is a fake for the loop caused by
  //a cycle that is specific to the hardware the code is
  //running on. This just resembles a cyclic call of the onCycle method.
  while(true){
    ManagerClass::cycleSignal();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The Output is

```c++
Hello World!
Destructor of TimeOut called!
```

Comment: This question confused me a little. One the timeout function goes out of scope the destructor of shared_ptr will be called. I am not sure what exactly the problem is. Could you please elaborate more.

Comment: @virusrocks Yes, but it seems to me, that either the capture or the static member function still claim a reference on the shared_ptr. As I mentioned, the destructor of TimeOut will not be called, when I use a shared_ptr in the way I did above.